# How to pass in client-side data when rendering server-side logic via AJAX in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**This is the problem I'm having**.  I have these filters and they each have their own url which are generated by a helper method `filter_url(filter_name)`. I want to update these filter urls asynchronously (AJAX) when the url changes (which also happens asynchronously and is pushed with HTML5's History API). However, I can't figure out how to update these filter urls because I need to know the name of the filter I am generating the url for (which is client-side in the `data-name` DOM attribute) but `filter_url` is server-side. *A sure-fire solution would be to move the `filter_url` logic client-side, but then I would have to maintain both client-side and server-side logic for handling filter urls which ain't DRY at all.*  So with that said, is what I'm trying to do possible or am I approaching it the wrong way? Thank you a thousand honey bunches of oats!

Perhaps SO should add some gist type of functionality for source code where you can split it by files. Maybe this might have better readability: https://gist.github.com/4c91435aefde9ad5846f. But I will also paste my code here in case my gist expires.

---

**`_filters.html.haml`**

```
%ul#filters
  - @filters.each do |filter|
    %li
      %a{:"data-name" => filter.name, :href => filter_url(@url_filters.add_to_url(filter.name))}
```

---

**`filters.js.coffee`**

```
$('#filters li a').live 'click', ->
  history.pushState(null, "", @href)  # This changes the url (not using hash bangs)
  $.getScript(@href)  # This will call index.js.coffee
```

---

**`filters_controller.rb`**

```
class FiltersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @url_filters = URLFilters.parse(request.fullpath)
  end
end
```

---

**`index.html.haml`**

```
= javascript_include_tag :filters
= render "filters"
```

---

**`index.js.coffee`**

```
$('#filters li a').each ->
  # This is the part I'm having trouble with. The code below obviously won't work but hopefully it'll give you an idea of what I'm trying to do
  # But basically I want to update each url filter url to account for the new url when the url changes
  $(this).attr('href', '<%= @url_filters.add_to_url($(this).data("name")) %>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I think I found a somewhat elegant solution to this.

I changed **`index.js.coffee`** to

```
# Render the partial and get a DOM fragme
filters = $('<%= escape_javascript(render("filters")) %>')

# Replace all filter urls from the ones in the DOM fragment
$('a.filter-url', filters).each ->
  $('#' + @id).attr('href', @href)  # Replace the href by selecting the id which is unique
```

and then also changing the partial **`_filters.js.coffee`** to

```
%ul#filters
  - @filters.each do |filter|
    %li
      %a{:id => "#{filter.name}-#{filter.value}", :href => filter_url(@url_filters.add_to_url(filter.name))}
```

So what I'm doing now is rendering the filters partial and creating a DOM fragment from that and using jQuery to select all the filter urls within that DOM fragment. Then, I am replacing the DOM fragment urls with the ones in the current view. Seems to work well, but I'm open to any other ideas! Hopefully this will help others who run into a similar scenario.